# xlrd. Printing one row at a time. trouble incrementing rows

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script that will pull one row of excel at a time and print it. I would like to use a method to change the row. I am able to get the value of the row to change (variable rrowx) but when I print the currentRow string, I get the original row and not the newly adjusted row.

```
import xlrd
class Loader(object): ## engine to load and unload spread sheets 
                      ## then sets them to a variable
     # set the variables
     workbook = " "      # name of the file
     sheetCount = 0      # amount of sheets in the spreadsheet
     sheetNumber = 0     # current sheet (index)
     rowCount = 0        # amount of rows in the spreadsheet
     currentSheet = " "  # name of current sheet
     topRow = " "        # row 0 string
     currentRow = " "    # row x string
     global rrowx
     rrowx = 0

     # begin the load  
     workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')
     sheetCount = workbook.nsheets
     sheetNames = workbook.sheet_names()
     currentSheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(sheetNumber)
     #topRow = currentSheet.row_values(rowx=rrowx, start_colx=scolx, end_colx=ecolx)
     currentRow = currentSheet.row_values(rowx=rrowx)

    #  methods to navigate the sheet 
     def nextrow(self):
        global rrowx
        print(rrowx)
        rrowx += 1 
        print(rrowx)
        return rrowx

spreadsheet = Loader()
## Debuggin prints
print(spreadsheet.sheetNames)
print(spreadsheet.sheetCount)
print("What Sheet would you like to use? (Use numbers)")
spreadsheetadjust = int(input())                   # takes input as a interger
spreadsheet.currentSheet = spreadsheetadjust - 1   # takes input and -1 for index value
print ('Current sheet name: %s' % spreadsheet.currentSheet)# prints current sheet name
print('top row:')
#print(spreadsheet.topRow)
print('row 1 ')
print(spreadsheet.currentRow)
print("NextRow")
spreadsheet.nextrow()
print(spreadsheet.currentRow)
```

I thought after changing the rrowx variable and calling print again on the currentRow would change the row that is printed. But instead I am getting the same row printed twice, even though I can see the value of rrowx is changing with the prints I added in the method.

disclosure: I've only been programming for a month so sorry if this is a easy answer i'm just missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you read python object oriented basics. You have multiple issues with your code, I will mention some:

- Your class variables are class variables, meaning all instances of
  the class will share the same variable. so if you create multiple
  instances of your class, you will get unexpected/undesired behavior.
- The use of a `global` variable is not recommended, especially when you
  can do without it.
- You don't need to initialize variables in python
- In your implementation you have 
  `spreadsheet.currentSheet = spreadsheetadjust - 1` which will cause you to fail even if you fix
  your problem. You want 
  `spreadsheet.sheetNumber = spreadsheetadjust - 1`

Here is code that works with proper usage of python classes:

```
import xlrd


class Loader:
    def __init__(self, path_to_xlsx='test.xlsx'):
        self.sheetNumber = 0
        self.rrowx = 0
        self.workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path_to_xlsx)
        self.sheetCount = self.workbook.nsheets
        self.sheetNames = self.workbook.sheet_names()
        self.currentSheet = self.workbook.sheet_by_index(self.sheetNumber)
        self.currentRow = self.currentSheet.row_values(rowx=self.rrowx)

    def nextrow(self):
        self.rrowx += 1
        self.currentRow = self.currentSheet.row_values(rowx=self.rrowx)


spreadsheet = Loader()

print("What Sheet would you like to use? (Use numbers)")
spreadsheetadjust = int(input())  # takes input as a interger
spreadsheet.sheetNumber = spreadsheetadjust - 1  # takes input and -1 for index value

print('Current sheet name: %s' % spreadsheet.currentSheet)  # prints current sheet name
print(spreadsheet.currentRow)

spreadsheet.nextrow()
print(spreadsheet.currentRow)
```